# Creating CNAMES in Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, cname-record

I used to host my site in Bluehost, but now I am moving to AWS, and I need to move my DNS configurations, and this is where I have some questions. first in bluehost I have this CNAMES and TXT records.

[image: These are my CNAMES]

[image: These are my TXT records]

but the problem is that amazon does not give me the chance to create these configurations as I do in bluehost, this is How I create in aws

[image: AWS TXT records]

[image: CNAME aws records]

Which is the correct way to migrate these configurations?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What previously was called "host record" is now called "name" in the UI and previous "points to" and "txt value" all map to "value". So you will just need to do some copy and pasting. You can put the same TTL or another value like the default 300 (seconds). What did you try and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the CNAMEs, "host record" becomes "name", and "points to" becomes "value".

For the TXT records, "host record" becomes "name" (a `@` host just means leave "name" blank in AWS), and "txt value" becomes "value". You have to surround the value with `"` marks.

In both cases, TTL is up to you. A lower TTL means updates to your DNS records are seen everywhere more rapidly, but comes with an increased (but generally pretty miniscule) cost due to more frequent DNS queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if I understand correctly, in aws I need to create one CNAME and TXT record for each row in the Bluehost images? each one with each value?. and the name will always have the domain at the end?

Comment: Yes, each row is a record, and will need a corresponding record in Route 53. AWS shows the domain as part of the host - it's just a stylistic choice on their part. Don't overthink it.